# Cannot use String in Apex REST

Tags: javascript, apexrest, string

I'm trying to use `String.escapeEcmaScript(data)` in an Apex REST class, but it seems like `String` class is not visible.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/Test/*')
global class TestREST {

  @HttpPost
  global static void createTest(String message)
  {
    RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{ "message" : "' + String.escapeEcmaScript(message) + '" }');
  }

}
```

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible to use this class since it's not global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should be:

```
message.escapeECMAScript();
```

escapeECMAScript is not a static method of the string class, it must be called from an existing string object

Comment: Also, it would be advised to check to make sure `message` is not null prior to calling `escapeECMAScript()` on it so that you don't throw a NPE.